# I'm parsing a api in json array form but it show error as "Unexpected response code 403 for (url)"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-volley

[This is screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuRdJ.png)

Here is my code for fectching data

```
 private fun fetchdata() {
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    val url =
        "http://newsapi.org/v2/everything?domains=wsj.com&apiKey=APIKEY"

    val jsonObjectRequest =   JsonObjectRequest(
        Request.Method.GET, url, null,
        {
            val newsJSONArray = it.getJSONArray("articles")
            val newsArray = ArrayList<News>()
            for (i in 0 until newsJSONArray.length()) {
                val newsJSONObject = newsJSONArray.getJSONObject(i)
                val news = News(
                    newsJSONObject.getString("author"),
                    newsJSONObject.getString("title"),
                    newsJSONObject.getString("description"),
                    newsJSONObject.getString("urlToImage")
                )
                newsArray.add(news)
            }
            mAdapter(this, newsArray)

        }, {

        })
     fun getHeaders():MutableMap<String,String>{
        val headers=HashMap<String,String>()
        headers["Content-type"]

        return headers
    }


}
```

And i got this error

```
11-13 19:31:13.104 4688-4709/com.example.volley_demo E/Volley: [254] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for http://newsapi.org/v2/everything?domains=wsj.com&apiKey=APIKEY
11-13 19:31:14.929 4688-4709/com.example.volley_demo D/Volley: [254] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ] http://newsapi.org/v2/everything?domains=wsj.com&apiKey=APIKEY 0xc16ea6dd NORMAL 1> [lifetime=4644], [size=11258], [rc=403], [retryCount=1]
11-13 19:31:14.930 4688-4709/com.example.volley_demo E/Volley: [254] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for http://newsapi.org/v2/everything?domains=wsj.com&apiKey=APIKEY
```

Comment: Do NOT publish your API key here!

Comment: did u found any fix for that?